# push notification in googledrive for android using GCM

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-drive-android-api

android google drive -its a pull notification (my understanding)i.e if changes done by webbrowser for subscribed folder then it only works in android if the Drive API downloads changes from the server for same device.
I want in my application- if i don't want to refresh by downloading (automatic notification of of folder metadata changes(file updated,added or deleted)) .

Is  push notification in googledrive for android using GCM  possible if I dont want to use restapi of googledrive .

Is there any way to do push notifications instead of using restApi of googledrive.

Ist -Can I have a working sample of google drive push notifiction  by using GCM for android using appengine for googleservice account that will notify if there any changes in googledive folder (note don't want to use restApi of googledrive,I want to use google drive android api ).

2nd- sample- push notification rest api of googledrive by using service account that will notify in  android device for changes in folder.

I think both Ist and 2nd only works with android only by using GCM () for notification of changes in folder or file.

My understanding about GCM we have to use server /domain to use it i.e why I am using google service account .
If I am using appengine -how google drive push notifications works with android via GCM.

Please  help for drive api accessing  for android notification
I am not able to proceed with this from last 3 weeks.
Thanks

Comment: if you would like to save all the hassles, why not try out notification in firebase cloud messaging? you can use firebase console to send out messages to your target audiences

Comment: please let me know is it can be used without restapi of google drive can you please provide sample how to handle it in GCM push  for   <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.drive.events.HANDLE_EVENT"/>

Comment: basically i want to know how to use GCM with google drive

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android),

> This quickstart illustrates the use of the Drive REST API in an Android application. However, in the majority of cases production **Drive apps will strongly benefit by making use of the Drive API for Android**, which is integrated with Google Play Services and offers better performance.

From that note, it clearly states that you may still go with push notifications through Google Drive Android API instead of using Google Drive REST API.

To know more about Google Drive Android API, you may use the following references:

- [Drive API for Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/)
- [Drive API for Android Quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)
- [Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

You may also check the links given from within the given references.

Comment: i set up my gcm account but still not able to know how do i connect it with google drive please let me know any sample or reference connection of GCM with google drive